# Passing parameters to a JQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, parameters

I'm creating HTML with a loop that has a column for Action. That column
is a Hyperlink that when the user clicks calls a JavaScript
function and passes the parameters...

example:

```
<a href="#" OnClick="DoAction(1,'Jose');" > Click </a>
<a href="#" OnClick="DoAction(2,'Juan');" > Click </a>
<a href="#" OnClick="DoAction(3,'Pedro');" > Click </a>
...
<a href="#" OnClick="DoAction(n,'xxx');" > Click </a>
```

I want that function to call an Ajax jQuery function with the correct
parameters.

Any help?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Using POST

```
function DoAction( id, name )
{
    $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "someurl.php",
         data: "id=" + id + "&name=" + name,
         success: function(msg){
                     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
                  }
    });
}
```

Using GET

```
function DoAction( id, name )
{
     $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "someurl.php",
          data: "id=" + id + "&name=" + name,
          success: function(msg){
                     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
                   }
     });
}
```

EDIT:

A, perhaps, better way to do this that would work (using GET) if javascript were not enabled would be to generate the URL for the href, then use a click handler to call that URL via ajax instead.

```
<a href="/someurl.php?id=1&name=Jose" class="ajax-link"> Click </a>
<a href="/someurl.php?id=2&name=Juan" class="ajax-link"> Click </a>
<a href="/someurl.php?id=3&name=Pedro" class="ajax-link"> Click </a>
...
<a href="/someurl.php?id=n&name=xxx" class="ajax-link"> Click </a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
   $('.ajax-link').click( function() {
         $.get( $(this).attr('href'), function(msg) {
              alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
         });
         return false; // don't follow the link!
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You don't have to change anything for GET, except changing TYPE to GET. Querystring will automaticly be build.

Comment: @Pim -- updated, thanks.  I was still pretty new to jQuery when I wrote this.

Comment: If you want to pass more than one parameter to the URL,use data as 
data:{id:'123' , name:"MyName"}
where the 123 is the value of the parameter id
myName is the value for the parameter name
the value here can be string or variable having the value to be passed.

just a simple trick to avoid string concatenation.

Comment: This accepted answer looks excellent to me, but I can't help but wonder, how would this look with the onClick bindings done in jQuery instead of right in the <a> tags?  I am led to believe jQuery is meant to handle the event bindings too.

Comment: @Marcus - the way I would actually do it is generate the URL as the href attribute. Then I'd add a click handler that gets the url from the anchor's href element and posts/gets that via ajax, returning false from the click handler.  I can add that as an alternative.

Comment: @tvanfosson I tried the click link get href alternative you posted (I did a copy/paste), but for some reason, this line --> $.get( $(this).attr('href') do nothing (no alert), any idea?

Comment: @PatricioCarvajalH. use the browser debugger to see if your request is failing for some reason - that would be my guess, that it's not getting back a valid response.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to do an ajax call or a simple javascript function, don't forget to close your function with the return false

like this:

```
function DoAction(id, name) 
{ 
    // your code
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to pass parameters to another page or to the function only?

If only the function, you don't need to add the $.ajax() tvanfosson added. Just add your function content instead.
Like:

```
function DoAction (id, name ) {
    // ...
    // do anything you want here
    alert ("id: "+id+" - name: "+name);
    //...
}
```

This will return an alert box with the id and name values.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

`#vote_links a` will catch all ids inside vote links div id ...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(\'#vote_links a\').click(function() {// alert(\'vote clicked\');
    var det = jQuery(this).get(0).id.split("-");// alert(jQuery(this).get(0).id);
    var votes_id = det[0];


   $("#about-button").css({
    opacity: 0.3
   });
   $("#contact-button").css({
    opacity: 0.3
   });

   $("#page-wrap div.button").click(function(){
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js">
</script>

 <script type="text/javascript">

  function omtCallFromAjax(urlVariable)
{ 
    alert("omt:"+urlVariable);
     $("#omtDiv").load("omtt.php?"+urlVariable);
}

 </script>
```

try this it work for me