# Jquery Post Data

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I need to insert/update data by using link or image

I need a code how to call post data using jquery !

< a href="some.asp" onClick="someaction, value to send" > Link

Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML

```
<a href="some.asp" class="upload">Link</a>
<input type="hidden" name="parameter" value="value-to-send" />
```

Code

```
$(function() {
    $('.upload').click( function() {
         $.post( $(this).attr('href'),
                 $(this).next('input[type=hidden]').serialize(),
                 function(data) { do something with returned data } );
         return false;  // cancel link default action
    });
});
```

You might also want to check out the documentation at [jQuery.com](http://jquery.com), especially the section on  [How jQuery Works](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in the [Jquery-Documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post#urldatacallbacktype) and change the function call by attaching the trigger later, so that it looks this-alike:

HTML:

```
<a id="myid" href="javascript:void(0);">My link</a>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Code:

```
    $("#myid").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'some.asp',
            success: function(result) {
                if(result != "false") {
                    $("#result").html(result);  
                } 
            }
          })    
    });
```

(untested)

Comment: But each link has diffrent value
like this 

<a href="#" onclick="$.post('test.asp', { profiid: '<%=(Recordset1.Fields.Item("ProfileID").Value)%>', seenby: '<%= Session("Username") %>' } );
">Remove </a>

Comment: then wrap it in a function: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/370359/passing-parameters-to-a-jquery-function