# add parameters to post request with jquery

Tags: jquery, post

How can I add parameters to a post request using .post or .ajax.
I tried:

```
var formData = $('form').serialize();
$.ajax({
url: "url",
data: formData,
type: "POST",
dataType: "dataType"
});
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Have you looked at this, previous, answer on SO?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/370359/passing-parameters-to-a-jquery-function

Comment: Yes I did, I was a little bit frustrated. I tried this alot.. I dont get why when I do the following,

`code`$(document).ready(function() {
 $('searchsubmit').click(function() {
  var formData = $('form').param();
  $.ajax({
   url: 'Search',
   type: "POST",
   data: formData,
   succes: function(data) {
    alert(data);
   }
  });
  alert("blabla");
 });
 alert("blabla");
});`code`

My servlet does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following acrashik's answer the following code works:

```
     var aData = table.fnGetData( this,0 );
     $.ajax({
         url: "MessageDetail",
         type: "POST",
         data: "messageid=" + aData,
         succes: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
     });
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add it to your formData before send?

```
var formData = $('form').serialize();
$.ajax({
    url: "url",
    data: formData + '&param=' + param_value,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "dataTpe"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "url",
    type: "POST",
    //dataType: 'json',
    data: formData,   
    success: function(data){

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.param`, not `.serialize`. The former returns an object, the latter returns a string.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/

Answer (score 0):

```
data: $('#myForm').serialize() + "&moredata=" + morevalue
```