# How to pass method parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var rF = function(callback) {
    alert("there2222");
    //additional calls
    $(document).trigger("lc", [callback]);
};
var pSl = function(callback) {
    var func = pSR; // how to pass callback parameter in function
    rF(func);
};
var pSR = function(callback, vars) {
    alert(callback);
    alert(vars);
};

$(document).on("lc", function(e, callback) {
    alert("theaaa");
    alert(callback, "ssss");

});

$('img').click(function() {
    pSl("lol");
});
```

Comment: pS1 is probably not visible to your jquery function.

Comment: try defining function without assigning to variable just a separate declaration for each function ex. function pS1(callback){}

Comment: Do the definition before the jquery call

Comment: i need to pass this callback to other method

Comment: can you provide me snippet what exactly you meant

Comment: I guess I don't understand what your asking by looking at your code.

Comment: using variable i want to pass the callback function like pSr(callback)

Comment: Your code [already seems to work](http://jsfiddle.net/fux3psd2/) but it's not at all clear what you're asking.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing parameters to a JQuery function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/370359/passing-parameters-to-a-jquery-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want to pass along `callback` to `pSR`. In that case you can use [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
var func = pSR.bind(null, callback);
```

or you put the call in another function:

```
rF(function() {
    pSR(callback);
});
```

However, the choice of the parameter name is questionable, since you seem to pass a string (not a function).