# How can I transfer an argument from html file to jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

I want to transfer the argument 7 from the html file

`<button id="buttonseven" onclick="buttonClick(7)">7</button>`

and how could I receive this argument in jQuery ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#buttonseven').click(function(){

    })
})
```

Comment: What can you / can't you change?  Is the html fixed? Or can you change it to `<button id="buttonseven" data-value="7">7</button>`?   Or is the param 7 always the same as the text 7?

Comment: Have a look at this [Stack Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370359/passing-parameters-to-a-jquery-function)

Answer (score 1):

you can save 7 in button attribute data-* form ,like code below:

```
<button id="buttonseven" data-value="7">click here</button>
```

so, from jQuery, you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#buttonseven').click(function(){
       let value = $(this).data('value')
       console.log(value)
    })
})
```

you can read jquery data() function [here](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

Answer (score 0):

I used this post [get the value of "onclick" with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415606/get-the-value-of-onclick-with-jquery) to get the value of your onclick function and this post [Get Substring between two characters using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14867835/get-substring-between-two-characters-using-javascript) to get the value between ( and ).

But the solution of **user1702660** is more simple than this one i think :)

```js
$("#buttonseven, .test").click(function() {
  var OnClickVal = $(this).get(0).attributes.onclick.nodeValue;
  var mySubString = OnClickVal.substring(OnClickVal.indexOf("(") + 1, OnClickVal.lastIndexOf(")"));
  console.log(mySubString);
});

function buttonClick(id) {
  // do something
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="buttonseven" onclick="buttonClick(7)">7</button><br>
<button onclick="buttonClick(37)" class="test">37</button>
```